# Is there a method in Java that mimics the cast of primitive type to Character?

Tags: java, casting, primitive-types

To simplify some bytecode analysis, I want to replace explicit (down)casts of primitive types in a Java program by calls to the equivalent method of the boxed type. In most cases it's simple:

```
double d = 42.0;
int i = (int)d;
```

Can be turned into

```
Double tmp = new Double(d);
int i = tmp.intValue();
```

This works for all signed types. But there is not such methods for `char` and `Character`. That is, Integer, Float, etc have the methods `intValue`, `floatValue`, etc. but none has a method `charValue`. Is there a jdk method to go from primitive type to char/Character?

So basically, is there something like this:

```
Integer num = new Integer(65);
char ch = num.charValue();
```

And the key is to not use `(char)`.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#charValue() ?

Comment: @ScaryWombat I think OP wants it on `java.lang.Integer` etc.

Comment: No there isn't as far as I understand your question

Comment: just as random remark: the jdi has a `PrimitiveValue` value interface that has a `charValue` method that implements this. But unfortunately, I can't just invoke that. It's also surprisingly hard to find what actually happens if you cast a (signed)double into an (unsigned)char. E.g., `(int)((char)Double.MIN_VALUE)` evaluates to zero. The same thing with `Double.MAX_VALUE` evaluates to `Character.MAX_VALUE`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're modifying bytecode, I think you do not need to cast to `char`. In the bytecode, the `char` type is a second-class citizen actually handled as an `int`. From [JVMS §4.9.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.9.2):

> An instruction operating on values of type `int` is also permitted to operate on values of type `boolean`, `byte`, `char`, and `short`.
>
> As noted in §2.3.4 and §2.11.1, the Java Virtual Machine internally converts values of types `boolean`, `byte`, `short`, and `char` to type `int`.)

So while you can't, say, assign an `int` to a `char` in the Java language without an explicit cast, you can do that in the bytecode, since they have the same "[verification type](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.10.1.2)", which is `int`. The bytecode representation of a `char` is just an `int` that happens to have its upper two bytes zero. So instead of:

```
char ch = num.charValue();
```

You would be able to get away with (in bytecode):

```
int ch = num.intValue() & 0x0000FFFF;
```

And then just pretend that `ch` is a `char` (e.g., pass it to methods that expect a `char` or store it in a `char` field or array).

However, if I understand it correctly, that's what the [`i2c`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-6.html#jvms-6.5.i2c) `int` to `char` cast instruction already does, so replacing it by an explicit AND operation is not going to be any simpler.

> It's also surprisingly hard to find what actually happens if you cast a (signed)double into an (unsigned)char.

When you cast from `float` or `double` to `byte`, `short`, or `char`, it first casts to `int`, which saturates out-of-range values to `Integer.MAX_VALUE` or `Integer.MIN_VALUE`, and then truncates the bytes of the `int` to fit the final type. See [JLS  §5.1.3 – Narrowing Primitive Conversion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.3). The truncation step means that conversion of out-of-range floating-point values to `byte`, `short`, or `char` is probably not going to give a useful result.

Comment: Wow! This is what StackOverflow is made for! Awesome answer and thank you very much.

Comment: fwiw, just to explain why I didn't use i2c: my analysis is actually on this jimple intermediate representation of the bytecode (see https://sable.github.io/soot/) and that re-adds the explicit cast to reduce the total number of instructions that you have to handle.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that there is any direct method in the classes to get a `char` representation. However, the simple solution is:

```
Integer num = new Integer(65);
char ch = (char)num.intValue();
```

I am sure that you thought of this. But there doesn't seem to be a better way.

Comment: That won't help ... the question is can I write a program that does not have the `(char)...` part...

Comment: I don't think there is any direct method. You can check the Javadoc. Since, it's not there, you can't get what you are asking for. What is the problem in type casting the int to char? After all, the byte code will be the same.

Comment: @MartinSchäf: No.  You can't.